# Animated GIF Creation Tool

Tags: software-recommendation, animation, gif

I would like to create some GIF animations to help explain some concepts on a website. This (from Wikipedia) is a good example of the sort of style I would like to use:

[image: Completing the square.gif]

This animation [appears](http://1ucasvb.tumblr.com/faq) to have been made using a custom PHP program and libraries. Is there a tool which can create similar animations without the need for explicit programming? Perhaps a tool which can generate an animation based on a list of descriptions, each having a simple meaning such as "rotate this item 180 degrees over 5 seconds"?

Comment: could you, please, embed example images to the post?

Comment: You could do it in after effects, but I have no idea if that's the best application for something like this. --- For example, exporting your animation to .gif is pretty convoluted in after effects. Technically it's impossible. You can however get around it by exporting a lossless video, import it to photoshop and then save it as a gif.

Comment: I would agree that what you've posted is far more a video project which happens to be saved as a gif. Trying to create that in a gif animation application will be a lesson in frustration.

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop and Flash can output animated gifs.
Flash or After Effects are more capable for advanced animation.

if you were going to use after effects you would need to export your animation as a image sequence and assemble that sequence as a gif in another application like photoshop.